# Android TV Layout gets auto deformed

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to develop a Launcher for Android TV, When ever i go to any other activity through the launcher and then return to the main UI, then the layout changes itself. Can anyone please let me know what is the mistake I am doing in designing the UI.

[image]

Here is XML code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        app:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <TextClock
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textClock"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    grid:targetApi="jelly_bean_mr1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:id="@+id/weather">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/sun" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:id="@+id/temp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/sdcard"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/ethernet"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_right"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/bluetooth"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_search"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/wifi"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="96dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:rowCount="2"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/grla2"
                android:id="@+id/grla"
                app:columnCount="6">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/movie"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    app:layout_column="0"
                    app:layout_row="0">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_movie"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Movies"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/news"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    app:layout_column="1"
                    app:layout_row="0">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_wcs"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="News"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/favorite"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    app:layout_column="2"
                    app:layout_row="0">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_market"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Favorites"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:id="@+id/game"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    app:layout_column="3"
                    app:layout_row="0">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_game"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Games"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/browser"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    app:layout_column="4"
                    app:layout_row="0">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_browser"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Browser"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/livetv"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    app:layout_column="5"
                    app:layout_row="0">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_xbmc"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Live TV"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/music"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    app:layout_column="0"
                    app:layout_row="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_music"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Music"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/social"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    app:layout_row="1"
                    app:layout_column="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_social"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Social"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/shopping"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                    app:layout_row="1"
                    app:layout_column="2">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_nv"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Shopping"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="3">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/slide_show"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
                </FrameLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                app:rowCount="4"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/grla2"
                app:columnCount="1">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/devices"
                    app:layout_column="0"
                    app:layout_row="0"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_devices"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Device"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/allapps"
                    app:layout_column="0"
                    app:layout_row="1"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_allapps"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="All Apps"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/settings"
                    app:layout_column="0"
                    app:layout_row="2"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_settings"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Settings"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_selector"
                    android:id="@+id/cleanup"
                    app:layout_column="0"
                    app:layout_row="3"
                    app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="1">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_speedup"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SpeedUp"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                </FrameLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_recycler"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please share image that what type of layout you need because your code is too long else share only that code and share that screen also that how it changed when switch from one activity to another activity

Comment: I have added the image of my layout. my problem is the largest banner in yellow with the "Diwali bumper offer tag" increases in size, both length and  breadth. As a result the other 4 views in the right gets affected. The deformation is different  each.

Comment: i am not getting what you said but i provide some code that will help you and i hope this will help you http://paste.ofcode.org/97nW5izkA7LQVK5DXVPeJy

Comment: The answer you suggested will work good to create the Layout. But if I develop a nested linear layout then I will not be able to use the transition of remote controller's navigation buttons. I guess I need to increment or decrement the row and column no. for the same.Nested Linear layout will not have row-column order( I don't know if it is possible).

Comment: I don't know more about that but i think it's not problem we linearlayout, have you read this https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html

Comment: please add this property `android:duplicateParentState="true"` in every linearlayout , i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

you use Relative layout then you need to care about align but if you want to divide your screen in equal part then use Linear Layout and weight also. I Paste some of code that is help you and i hope your problem is solved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight=".2"
           android:padding="5dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="40dp">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:gravity="bottom"
               android:background="@color/blue">

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Your Text"
                   android:textSize="20sp"
                   android:textColor="@color/black"/>
           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:gravity="bottom|right"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:background="@color/blue">

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Your Text"
                   android:textSize="20sp"
                   android:textColor="@color/black"/>
           </LinearLayout>

       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight=".8"
           android:paddingLeft="40dp"
           android:paddingRight="40dp"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight=".8"
               android:orientation="vertical">

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:padding="5dp"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                       android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                   </LinearLayout>

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                       android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                   </LinearLayout>

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                       android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                   </LinearLayout>

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                       android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                   </LinearLayout>

               </LinearLayout>

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:padding="5dp"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                       android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                   </LinearLayout>
                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                       android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                   </LinearLayout>
                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                       android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                   </LinearLayout>
                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                       android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                   </LinearLayout>
               </LinearLayout>

           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight=".2"
               android:padding="5dp"
               android:orientation="vertical">

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                   android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

               </LinearLayout>

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                   android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

               </LinearLayout>

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                   android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

               </LinearLayout>

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                   android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

               </LinearLayout>

           </LinearLayout>

       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight=".1"
           android:gravity="center">

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
       </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```